# Can i skin an object to a bone directly

Tags: rigging

I want to skin an object to a selected bone from an armature that has many, but skin it only to the selected bone.
Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yes a mesh can be a child of a single bone. This is possible.

- In pose mode select the bone of the armature. Object Mode again for convenience.
- Select the Mesh.
- Select the armature to parent Control P ... Menu Choice Bone
- Note the parent is Armature with Bone Subchoice

[image]

Comment: I know it's a hard question to understand, I want to SKIN an object to a bone, what you're showing me is parenting.

Comment: Use object constraints . Select your object and Copy location & Copy Rotation constraints to it. Select your armature, then required bone.Ensure your object pivot is properly set.